# Finding similar values in a hash/array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am trying to compute how many 'tips' a 'user' has in common with another user.
Here is my method doing so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tips, :inverse_of => :user
  ...
  public
  def tip_affinity_with(user)
    tipAffinity = 0

    user.tips.each do |tip|
      if self.tips.include?(tip)
        tipAffinity = tipAffinity + 1
      end
    end

    return tipAffinity
  end
end
```

I know that some users have tips that they have both rated, but in my table, the tipAffinity is 0 for all of the users.

What could be the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: Here is the join model, `Affinity`:

```
class Affinity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_A_id, :user_B_id, :tips_value, :tips_valid, :profile_value, :profile_valid, :value

  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :inverse_user, :class_name => "Users"

  validates :tips_value, presence: true
  validates :profile_value, presence: true
  validates :user_A_id, presence: true
  validates :user_B_id, presence: true

  before_update :set_value
  before_create :set_value

  private
  def set_value
    self.value = 0.7*self.tips_value + 0.3*self.profile_value
    #self.value = PredictionConfigs.find(1)*self.tips_value + (1 - PredictionConfigs.find(1))*self.profile_value #Use prediction configs
  end
end
```

I am indeed trying to find the intersection of two hashes. The two hashes are the tips of two users, one is `self`, the other is `user`.

Thanks again!

Comment: Some more information on your data structure would be relevant here.

Comment: What would be helpful to include?

Comment: How is a  User related to a Tip? Also worth noting that in Ruby variable names use underscore like `tip_affinity` and that the `return` statement on the last line is implied and can be omitted.

Comment: A user has_many tips and a tip has_many users. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Roughly that, yes, but that seems odd. You shouldn't have a many to many like that. You'd need to have a join model in the middle.

Comment: Well a user can rate many tips, and a tip can be rated by many users. That is why it has a many-to-many relationship, I presume. I did not build the relationship myself, I'm merely adding on to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77641/discussion-between-user107680-and-tadman).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is brutally inefficient, you might try:

```
(user.tips & self.tips).length
```

You really want to avoid loading models if you're not using the data contained within them. This should be possible to compute using only what's present in the database. Something like:

```
(user.tip_ids & self.tip_ids).length
```

Comment: I used this for the if statement. Now the tip value doesn't return 0 every time. But what exactly does this do?

Comment: This looks for the intersection (`&`) between tips from two different users. This presumes that the tips created by two users references the same Tip record. If not you may need to do some additional work.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are set up correctly, this can be done in the database with:

```
def tip_affinity_with(user)
  user.tips.where(id: tip_ids).count
end
```

It seems to me based on the comments (and your example code) that your models may not be set up correctly. Do you have a join model between users and tips? Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suggestions
  has_many :tips, through: :suggestions
end

class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tip
end

class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suggestions
  has_many :users, through: :suggestions
end
```

It'd help to see your `Tip` model. My guess is that `Tip` `belongs_to :user` and that's why you aren't getting any overlap between users, but I could be wrong.

Here's some more reading from the Rails guides on [`has_many :through` associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: I do. It's the affinity model. I will update the post above with it!

Comment: Please see my edit above which contains the `affinity` model.

Comment: I don't see any connection to `tips` in your `Affinity` class. Did you just forget to include it, or does it not exist?